# come up with a generalised formula for area of n sides with L meters of fence. consider a large number of n and compare that to a circle

Tags: calculus, area, polygons

questions before asked to compare area of a rectangle and isoceles triangle using 60m of fencing and then asked us to come up with a generalised form for L meters of fence showing that this is a maximum using calculus.